# Calling a function every 20 seconds in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, timer, bluetooth-lowenergy

There is a function I'm trying to call every 20 seconds using Timer(). I already tried as well with a while loop followed by a delay of 20 seconds, but ends up running out of memory or throws thread exceptions. How can I do this without making my app crash and run out of memory? For a matter of context, I'm building an app to communicate with a BLE device. I just started with Kotlin, so I'm not sure how to do this without breaking everything.

I just want call the same function because everytime it gets called, the value will be different each time.

BleExtensions.kt

```
fun BluetoothGatt.printGattTable() {

ConnectionManager.writeCharacteristic(device, BluetoothGattCharacteristic(
        UUID.fromString("6e400002-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e"),
        BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE,
        BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PERMISSION_WRITE
    ), bytes1)

}
```

ConnectionManager.kt

```
 fun writeCharacteristic(
        device: BluetoothDevice,
        characteristic: BluetoothGattCharacteristic,
        payload: ByteArray
    ) {

        val writeType = when {
            characteristic.isWritable() -> BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_DEFAULT
            characteristic.isWritableWithoutResponse() -> {
                BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_NO_RESPONSE
            }
            else -> {
                Timber.e("Characteristic ${characteristic.uuid} cannot be written to")
                return
            }
        }
        if (device.isConnected()) {
            enqueueOperation(CharacteristicWrite(device, characteristic.uuid, writeType, payload))
        } else {
            Timber.e("Not connected to ${device.address}, cannot perform characteristic write")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with:

```
Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate( object : TimerTask() {
        override fun run() {
            ConnectionManager.writeCharacteristic(device, BluetoothGattCharacteristic(
                UUID.fromString("6e400002-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e"),
                BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE,
                BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PERMISSION_WRITE
            ), bytes1)
        }
    }, 0, 20000)
```